Using File Input in Org Source Block?
I'm trying to run this C source block using input from a text file.
#+BEGIN_SRC C :includes <stdio.h>
  int c;
  c = getchar();
  while (c != EOF) {
    putchar(c);
    c = getchar();
  }
#+END_SRC

How can I handle "./example.txt" as my input?

On Linux at least (and probably other Unix systems and probably also on WSL), you can use input redirection as follows:
#+BEGIN_SRC C :includes <stdio.h> :cmdline < ./example.txt
  int c;
  c = getchar();
  while (c != EOF) {
    putchar(c);
    c = getchar();
  }
#+END_SRC


The :cmdline value is appended to the path of the executable and the whole thing is sent to a shell for evaluation, so redirection works.
You can find some information on the C implementation in Org Babel on Worg. However, :cmdline is only mentioned there with no examples of how to use it.
